# Can Forms Based Authentication be Used on Site Collection?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, security, forms-authentication

Is it possible to use forms based authentication/.net security for a site collection? I can see where I can configure a web application for FBA, but not for a site collection, which in my case is a host named site collection. Is it possible for both FBA and windows authentication to be used for a site collection, the issue being that both internal and external users should access the site, but I don't care to use cross domain trusted solutions, add external users to my domain.

If possible, how?

SharePoint 2013 SP1 Enterprise, Windows Server 2012 R2, SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication is Web App level Configuration.

But In your scenario, I would recommend this.

Extend your web application to different zone and configure the FBA on that zone. Now set the new Host name to the site collection for that extended zone.

http://blog.amhawkins.com/sharepoint/adding-an-alternative-url-to-the-extranet-zone-for-a-host-named-site-collection-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: this was good information, especially since it exposed my ignorance of the many sharepoint containers and their hierarchies.

farm --> web application --> site collection --> site --> pages.

I now have better information for designing my farm and how to support security.

thank you!